# Table Design for Parent Child Task

Tags: sql, design-patterns, parent-child

I am Simulating Microsoft Office Project 2010 in ASP.NET. Here is my table design for saving tasks and its parent-child relationship Task. Is this Good Design pattern ?

[image]

Comment: See this for various models regarding [Storing Hiararchical Data in databases](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/)

Comment: And this SO question: [What are the Options for Storing Hierarchical Data in a Relational Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just one parent for each of your nodes (which is true in Microsoft Office) move the reference field to the main table as **parent_id**.

Comment: No its an application like a Task can have subtask and in turn tat subtask may hav another subtask and it goes on